# How to get mapserver to work

Tags: apache, gis, mapserver

I've been working with MapServer for about 2 hours now , but it seems alittle bit complicated to get started with. 
So here's my question
Is there any way to get mapserver to show a simple map of whole world in which I can move the map to see different parts of the world ?
( from what I've learnt so far , it just shows you the Map you've passed the mapserv cgi , and the map is static and cannot be moved ! )

EDIT : 
I'm still wondering if I can have a simple map for the whole world or a country or whatever !  Should I be Writing .Map Files for everything On my own ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay , so after looking it up and struggling alittle , I found some JS libraries to do this, One of the was [Open Layers](http://openlayers.org/). You just have to reference it at the beginning of your html page like :

```
<script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
```

and then you can have zoom and move options for your map by binding MapServer data as follows to the OpenLayers init function.

```
Var map, layer;

function init(){
    map = new OpenLayers.Map( 'map' );
    layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.MapServer( "NAME",
       "http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv", {map: 'PATH_TO_.MAP'} );
    map.addLayer(layer);
    map.zoomToMaxExtent();
}
```

And lots of cool tutorials can be found in [spatialhorizons.com](http://spatialhorizons.com/2007/11/14/using-mapserver-2-generating-map-tiles/).
Hope this helps someone :)

Comment: +1 but it's probably better to use a WMS layer in OpenLayers and configure MapServer to serve up WMS. The Layer.Mapserver object in OpenLayers is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

MapServer is just that, a MAP SERVER. It sounds like you are currently using a cgi script to display a hosted map. WMS providers like MapServer host data that can be viewed using a WMS client application. There are many such applications. You will need a more sophisticated client application to connect to the MapServer in order to perform more complicated map manipulations.

check out [GoogleEarth](http://www.data.gov.bc.ca/dbc/geo/wms/google_earth_connect.page)

or [NASA WorldWind](http://www.worldwindcentral.com/wiki/WMS)

or I haven't used [this](http://mapserver.refractions.net/phpwms/phpwms-cvs/) yet but it looks like it might be the easiest, if least dependable.

Comment: That's right, But i was looking for a way to have like 'dynamic maps' for mapserver, not other GISEngines ( google maps , earth or whatever else ) and I'm not using any cgi script , I'm just passing the mapserv binary file ( created after compiling it ) the path to a map file with mode=map , and it shows the map , nothing to zoom , move or whatever, and it seems like i have to write a .map file with layers or ... for every single spot of the world this way!

Comment: Ok well mapserver is not a very good client. That's like using apache to browse webpages. Have you tried mode=browse?

Comment: Getting this in browse mode :
 Traditional BROWSE mode requires a TEMPLATE in the WEB section, but none was provided.

Answer (score 1):

First MapServer is the GIS server side technology. The zoom in/ pan is the client side behavior in my opinion.

When we look at the moment that user pan/zoom at one web application, what really happened is the front end application get the pan/zoom event and make calls to mapserver to get the new map to return to the client side.

So it is more likely your leaflet, Google map API, Openlayers, etc. are handling the detection of the client movement and parse it into new getmap request and send the request to mapserver to get the response.

What you saw from the MapServer using get request is static and it is suppose to be so. The dynamic part is happened in the client side  to make dynamic calls from the front end application to make these static calls. That is interactive when client side dynamically sending out request and refresh the map from the response.